Why is Android limited to two profiles: the Work, and default (Home) profile?
Is there any reason that AOSP is limited to Home (default) and a Work profile? Is it possible to compile AOSP for n-profiles? Or to add another profile with Magisk?

Did you see/find: https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/multi-user#applying_the_overlay
